How to Generate pytest Code Coverage Report for Manual testing without writing unit test cases
In java we can generate code coverage report for manual testing by using Jacoco agent. Want to do the same for python application. We want to run the application on server, capture the manual testing until the server is stopped and then generate the code coverage report. We can't write test cases or automate the testing. How can we generate coverage report from Manual testing.
Please note that we need the coverage report from manual testing and not from writing test cases.

This question is similar to: How to properly use coverage.py in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The above link generates coverage report from unit test cases. we want to generate coverage report from manual testing.

The Coverage.py API documentation shows how you can programmatically call coverage:

import coverage

cov = coverage.Coverage()
cov.start()

# .. call your code ..

cov.stop()
cov.save()

cov.html_report()


Write a wrapper around your code that starts coverage and then starts your application and allows you to keep running your code until you have performed all your manual testing and then when you have finished, clean up after your application and close it down and finally call the methods to stop coverage and generate the report.

Thanks a lot, I can generate report for manual testing now.
